# Owin Startup Class won't Start on IIS

Tags: iis, owin

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Test.TestStartup))]

namespace Test
{
    public class TestStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("c:/Test/owin.txt", "started");

            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I have a very simple OWIN startup class. When I run this on my local, it executes just fine.

When I try to publish this app to an IIS server, I can't get it to start.

The app pool is in Integrated mode and using 4.0.

I have tried including owin:AutomaticAppStartup = "true" in my web.config.

The Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb dll is present in the bin directory of my deployed app.

Everyone has full control on the 'Test' directory.

Any ideas? I am completely stuck.

Comment: Does your app pool's identity have write premission to write owin.txt file on C: drive? It may be failing at this line itself. File.AppendAllText("c:/owin.txt", "started");

Comment: Changed to a Test directory and granted Everyone full control. Still didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.